# What causes Timeout expired SqlExceptions in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, sqlexception

My application keeps running into Timeout Expired SqlExceptions.  The thing is that this query is one that will simply have to run for a decent amount of time.  I'm having trouble figuring out where this exception is occurring though.  Is this a timeout that's created at the database server or is it happening in my program?  Or if it could be both, how do I figure out which one it is?

And lastly, how do I extend the timeout period?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is likely that you are running over the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout.aspx) set on your DataContext. This defaults to 30 seconds.

All you need to do is set the property on the DataContext before you execute your query.

Comment: And how am I supposed to that?

Answer (score 15):

increase timeout = **BAD**
fix query = **GOOD**

I'm not sure of all the details involved, but in general the followng applies:

when a query runs slow do the following in management studio:

- run SET ShowPlan_All ON
- run your query
- look at the output for the word "scan". your problem is there.

"Scan" = touch each row (table or index). Would you like to "scan" a phone book looking for one number or use the index?

Comment: We've tuned the query about as much as we can. Unfortunately, there's only so much you can do to speed up the process of pulling 15k records out of a table of 2 million records through a linked server.

Comment: edit your question and include the output from SET ShowPlan_All ON

Comment: @Jason Baker, I have many queries that join on multiple tables with more rows than your 2 million, and they run a lot faster than 30 seconds.  You say "We've tuned the query about as much as we can", and that is why I was offering my help.

Answer (score 3):

This is probally occuring becuase the default timeout is 30 seconds. You can change this by setting a Timeout attribute on the connection string. Alternatley you can set this on the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout.aspx).

Here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQ2SQLCommandTimeout.aspx) on code project about this.